# Appium Android XPath Wildcard Class

Tags: appium, appium-android

I'm trying to write an XPath query for Appium tests for an Android app where I find an element by it's ID regardless of it's class.

This is the XPath I'm trying but it doesn't seem to work: `//*[@id='toFind']`

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was two fold.

Firstly you need to use `resource-id` not `id` also Resource ID can be a longer value than the one you are looking for so you need to `contains`

`//*[contains(@resource-id, 'toFind')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//*[@resource-id='toFind'] OR //*[@resource-id="toFind"]
```